# Google Vision barcode library not found

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode, google-vision, android-vision

I'm trying to use the new feature in Google Play Services (Vision) to add QR code scanning to my application. But when I run my app I get this:

```
I/Vision﹕ Supported ABIS: [armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
D/Vision﹕ Library not found: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
I/Vision﹕ Requesting barcode detector download.
```

I have declared barcode dependency as per tutorial:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="barcode" />
```

I tried reinstalling the app and restarting the phone, nothing helps.

Using Google Play Services 7.8, version installed on the device is 7.8.11.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0'
```

Code used for creating the barcode detector:

```
boolean initBarcodeDetector() {
    final BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeTrackerFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(this);
    final MultiProcessor<Barcode> multiProcessor = new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeTrackerFactory)
            .build();
    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .build();
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(multiProcessor);

    if (barcodeDetector.isOperational() == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.barcode_not_operational, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

the above close returns false and finishes activity because `barcodeDetector.isOperational()` returns `false`.

Comment: Where is your code? Where are your dependencies from your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Added relevant dependency and code

Comment: I just had the same problem, and I fixed it by freeing up disk space on my device. It works great now, but before that, it would never download the dependency.

Comment: Could someone help me with the similar question related to android-vision?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715573/media-recorder-with-google-vision-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It started working after I cleared cache and freed up some space. I had "only" 400mb free space and there was no error message which would indicate that.

Comment: Well, this was the answer in my case, I had to free up some space on my device.

Comment: We've had one user that reported he had around 890MB free and it still didn't download the libraries. Do you remember how much space you had when it worked?

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I even implemented the lowStorage check, but that never notified me of low storage. After I deleted some data and my free space went just a little bit over 10%, it immediately worked/downloaded the libs.

Comment: I am not very much sure. But using latest library might resolved that issue. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'

Comment: me  getting this logcat  Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

Answer (score 9):

Google has confirmed a bug that they will fix soon, which prevents you in some cases to use this library of barcode/face-detection (link [**here**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90)) :

> - A service required by Mobile Vision is now disabled due to a serious bug in that service. This will prevent users who have not
>     already used face or barcode detection from using those features. We
>     do not recommend adding new Mobile Vision features to your app until
>     this issue is fixed.
> - For apps that already use Mobile Vision features, check FaceDetector.isOperational() or BarcodeDetector.isOperational() to
>     confirm detector readiness before using the face or barcode detector.

It's also written in some issues reported on Google's github sample repo:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues

Example ([**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/95#issuecomment-220163073)) :

> There is a known issue with the new version of GMSCore (v9) that was
>   just released today.

Comment: yeah, according to the release notes the bug should be fixed: https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes#bug_fixes

Answer (score 5):

**Based on the documentation here:** https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary **and here:** https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector#isOperational()

### Documentation:

> **public boolean  isOperational()**
>
> Indicates whether the detector has all of the required dependencies
>   available locally in order to do detection.
>
> When an app is first installed, it may be necessary to download
>   required files. If this returns false, those files are not yet
>   available. Usually this download is taken care of at application
>   install time, but this is not guaranteed. In some cases the download
>   may have been delayed.
>
> If your code has added a processor, an indication of the detector
>   operational state is also indicated with the detectorIsOperational()
>   method. You can check this in your app as it processes detection
>   results, and can convey this state to the user if appropriate.
>
> Returns •true if the detector is operational, false if the dependency
>   download is in progress

**and**

> **public boolean  detectorIsOperational()**
>
> Returns true if the detector is operational, false if it is not
>   operational. In the non-operational case, the detector will return no
>   results.
>
> A detector may be non-operational for a while when starting an app for
>   the first time, if a download is required to obtain the associated
>   library and model files required to do detection.

It looks like your device needs to finish downloading the libraries through Google Play Services in order for your application to work right away.

### Based on the Google Samples(a comment in the source):

```
        // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
        // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
        // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
        // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
        // and/or faces.
        //
        // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
        // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
        // downloads complete on device.
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/multi-tracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/multitracker/MultiTrackerActivity.java#L156

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really answer the question. We already knew that. The thing is, a lot of users are on Wi-Fi, have tons of empty space and the libraries still refuse to download. Then for some of the users, they start working just fine after a few days. A more complete explanation, preferably from Google, would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this, the vision library could not be found on one of my test devices, although the console showed a request of the library on every start of the app, but never finished. I tested on Nexus 4,5 Motorola X2, Samsung S 2-6 and various other devices, the S5 was the only devices with the Problem. There was enough free space with over 2Gb, after hard resetting the device the scanning worked instantly as intended.

Comment: resetting the device did it for me

Answer (score 2):

in Sep, 2020:
this version has it:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had same experience.
(sorry I can't comment to add my case because I only have 1 rep)
I am using Nexus 5 (2013) with marshmallow (6.0).
I started with 1gb free space and didn't work and didn't work at 2gb.
I ended up freeing another 1gb (so 3gb free space) then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Vision operation is restored in Google Play Services v9.2
https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes#google_play_services_92

> Release Notes
>
> Here are the updates to the Mobile Vision API, corresponding to the
>   Google Play Services releases.
>
> Google Play Services 9.2
>
> Bug Fixes
>
> Mobile Vision operation is restored in Google Play Services v9.2.
>   Users with the new version will be able to download the required files
>   and make use of application features powered by Mobile Vision. The
>   Google Play Services update also includes a configuration update as
>   part of the fix for Mobile Vision. Normally this is updated once every
>   several days, but it will also occur on phone reboot (though this it
>   is throttled, so this is not guaranteed to update the configuration).
>   Since file download errors can still occur (e.g. if there is
>   insufficient storage on the device), we advise Google Play Services
>   developers to call FaceDetector.isOperational() or
>   BarcodeDetector.isOperational() to check for detector readiness and
>   degrade feature operation accordingly.