# Google Play Services Crashes on Android 2.3 Vision API

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-2.3-gingerbread, google-vision, android-vision

I'm using the Android Vision API for a QR-code-scanner which works fine on several Android devices and versions, except for Android 2.3.x devices. When I open the QR-code-scanner a dialog is shown that the google-play-services crashes. In the Logcat I see the following error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncOperationService[VisionDependencyIntentService]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.SharedPreferences.getStringSet
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.service.VisionDependencyIntentService.b(SourceFile:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.service.VisionDependencyIntentService.a(SourceFile:174)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.service.a.a.a(SourceFile:45)
        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.f.run(SourceFile:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

This is the code of my fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  Activity activity = getActivity();

  preview = (CameraSourcePreview) view.findViewById(R.id.preview);

  int connectionResult = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
  if (connectionResult == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
  {
     // create a barcode detector.
     BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(activity).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
           .build();

     // create a processor to filter qr-codes and a tracker to handle the selected qr-code.
     barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new QrCodeProcessor(barcodeDetector, new QrCodeTracker(this)));

     if (barcodeDetector.isOperational())
     {
        // Creates and starts the camera.
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(activity, barcodeDetector)
              .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK).setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
              .setRequestedFps(15.0f).build();
     }
     else
     {
        showAlert(R.string.QrCodeScanner_alert_play_services_not_operational_header,
              R.string.QrCodeScanner_alert_play_services_not_operational_body);
     }
  }
  else
  {
     PlatformUtil.handlePlayServicesError(activity, connectionResult);
  }
}
```

according to the Google Play Services guide Android 2.3 should be supported:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

I also tried freeing up some space and did a factory reset as suggested in: [Google Vision barcode library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099530/google-vision-barcode-library-not-found/32100941#32100941) without any succes.

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  We will take a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this particular API relies upon `SharedPreferences.getStringSet()`, which according to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet), was only introduced in API 11 (Android v3.0 Honeycomb).

You won't be able to use this on 2.x devices.

Comment: So should I report this as an Android bug?

Comment: Could someone help me with the similar question related to android-vision?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715573/media-recorder-with-google-vision-api