# Media Recorder with Google Vision API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, google-vision, android-vision

I am using the [FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) sample from the Android vision API. However, I am experiencing difficulty in recording videos while the overlays are drawn on them.

One way is to store bitmaps as images and process them using FFmpeg or Xuggler to merge them as videos, but I am wondering if there is a better solution to this problem if we can record video at runtime as the preview is projected.

**Update 1:**
I updated the [following](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/ui/camera/CameraSourcePreview.java) class with media recorder, but the recording is still not working. It is throwing the following error when I call triggerRecording() function:

**MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4**

and I have external storage permission in the Manifest file.

**Update 2:**

I have fixed the above issue in the code and moved the setupMediaRecorder() in the onSurfaceCreated callback. However, when I stop recording it throws the runtime-exception. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop%28%29) if there is no video/audio data Runtime exception will be thrown.

So, what am I missing here?

```
public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSourcePreview";

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    /**
     * Whether the app is recording video now
     */
    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());

        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(480, 640);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        //int rotation = mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        //int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(ORIENTATIONS.get(0));
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();

        mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                Timber.d(mr.toString() + " : what[" + what + "]" + " Extras[" + extra + "]");
            }
        });
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException {
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            stop();
        }

        mCameraSource = cameraSource;

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mStartRequested = true;
            startIfReady();
        }
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        start(cameraSource);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
        if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
            mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            if (mOverlay != null) {
                Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                if (isPortraitMode()) {
                    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                    // 90 degrees
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                } else {
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                }
                mOverlay.clear();
            }

            mStartRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = true;
            surface.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            // setup the media recorder
            try {
                setUpMediaRecorder();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                startIfReady();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            if (size != null) {
                width = size.getWidth();
                height = size.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = width;
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
        }

        final int layoutWidth = right - left;
        final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

        // Computes height and width for potentially doing fit width.
        int childWidth = layoutWidth;
        int childHeight = (int) (((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);

        // If height is too tall using fit width, does fit height instead.
        if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
            childHeight = layoutHeight;
            childWidth = (int) (((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPortraitMode() {
        int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return false;
        }
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return true;
        }

        Timber.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
        return false;
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo() {
        try {
            // Start recording
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
        // UI
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        // Stop recording
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
    }

    public void triggerRecording() {
        if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
            stopRecordingVideo();
            Timber.d("Recording stopped");
        } else {
            startRecordingVideo();
            Timber.d("Recording starting");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to couple of other reasons, I changed my approach and instead used OpenCV with GLSurfaceView. Checkout my other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33368655/1053097

Comment: @muneikh looks like you need to to unlock camera before starting recording. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** From Android Lollipop, a [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) API was introduced which in conjunction with MediaRecorder can be used to save a `SurfaceView` to a video file. [This example shows how to output a `SurfaceView` to a video file.](http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/)

**Solution 2:** Alternatively, you can use one of the neat Encoder classes provided in the [Grafika repository](https://github.com/google/grafika). Note that this will require you to port the `FaceTracker` application so that it is using OpenGL to perform all rendering. This is because Grafika samples utilise the OpenGL pipeline for fast read and write of texture data.

There is a minimal example which achieves exactly what you want using a `CircularEncoder` in the  [`ContinuousCaptureActivity`](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) class. This provides an example of [Frame Blitting](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting), simultaneously displaying frame buffer data to the screen and outputting to a video.

The major change would be to utilise a Grafika `WindowSurface` instead of a `SurfaceView` for the FaceTracker application, this sets up the EGL Context allowing you to save frame buffer data to a file via the Encoder. Once you can render everything to the WindowSurface, it is trivial to set up recording in the same way as the `ContinuousCaptureActivity` class.