# Android vision barcode-reader not working with some Samsung devices

Tags: android, camera, google-play-services, google-vision, android-vision

I'm using the barcode-reader project in two Samsung devices (SM-N9005 or SM-G920F) and they are not capable of recognize any barcode. There are no problems in others like One plus one, or others Samsung devices like S3 or S4.

There is not a problem of the autofocus, because it is working fine, the barcode is focus properly.

With this devices, the camera opens but nothing happens.

HELP please.

Answer (score 2):

Have you take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100941/2295917) already ?

It looks like freed some space is [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123937/2295917) effective, have you enough space on this devices (more than 10% of the total space) ?

Comment: No, this issue is so weird. Zxing or Zbar doesn't give any issue in these phones, so this google barcode reader is not the best option now.