# Scan QR code from Camera

Tags: android, qr-code

I have a requirement where in I need to scan QR code from my app, for which I need to open camera and scan the code. I followed instructions given in [Xamarin.Android - QR Code Reader By Mobile Camera](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-qr-code-reader-by-mobile-camera/), but I am getting this exception :

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector$Builder
```

Is there anything I missed here? 
I am using `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision` version `60.1142.1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Vision barcode library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099530/google-vision-barcode-library-not-found)

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues