# Scanning QR Codes using barcodeDetector by OPPO CPH1923 device

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-camera, qr-code, google-vision

I have a project that scan `QR Codes` . It works fine using `Samsung mobiles`  but I can't scan `QR Codes`  using  `OPPO CPH1923 device` . I made a debug and I found that , debugger didn't get into
`receiveDetections` override function .I don't know why this device dose that and I'm wasting my time .

I use `Google mobile vision API`

> Note : I don't have a sim card in the mobile

Here is my code

```
barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(MainActivity.this,barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640,480)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();


        surface.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                    else {

                        cameraSource.start(holder);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                scannerDilaog.dismiss();
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodeSparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();



                if(barcodeSparseArray!=null&&barcodeSparseArray.size()>0){
                    if(!flag) {
                        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int times =0;
                               
                                //flag = true;
                                cameraSource.stop();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("result", barcodeSparseArray.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                                Log.e("result"," "+barcodeSparseArray.valueAt(0).displayValue);

                                if(!flag) {
                                    times++;
                                    Log.d("times"," "+times);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                flag=true;
                                cameraSource.stop();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution at this part of this Answer
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100941/11567530)

**Based on the Google Samples(a comment in the source):**

```
// Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
    // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
    // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
    // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
    // and/or faces.
```